# All connected graphs without the induced copy of the path

Tags: graph-theory

Following this [questions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3564039/describe-all-graphs-that-do-not-contain-p-3-as-an-induced-subgraph), I am interested in determining all connected graphs with the property that they do not contain an induced copy of the path on two edges. My idea is: a singleton $K^1$ and complete graph of $K^2$ since these two graphs contain an edge less than 2. I am not sure about that and I need a better idea.

Comment: "the path on two edges" is $P_3$, isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a very short proof of the following statement.

> If a connected graph $G$ is an induced $P_3$-free graph, then $G$ is a
> complete graph.

Let $v$ be an arbitrary vertex of $G$ and $N(v)$ be all its neighbors.
Then there are no vertices lying outside $N(v)\cup\{v\}$, otherwise $G$ contains an induced $P_3$ graph (try to figure out why).
It follows that $V(G)=N(v)\cup\{v\}$ and $\operatorname{deg}(v)=|V(G)|-1$.
Since this is true for every vertex $v\in V(G)$, then $G$ is a complete graph.

Comment: Thanks for your effort. Is it right to conclude that all complete graphs satisfy the property of the question?

Comment: Another post that I think is the same question here. Please verify that for me for sake of duplication of questions https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1162687/let-g-be-a-simple-graph-having-no-isolated-vertex-and-no-induced-subgraph-with Thanks in advance @kabenyuk

Comment: @holala: Yes, your question duplicates [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1162687), and my answer is very similar to Rebecca J. Stones' answer. 
At the same time I will answer your question from the previous comment. Any complete graph is $P_3$-free.

Comment: Thinking about the question, I see "the path on two edges" to be $P_2$ since the number of edges of this path is 2. Am I wrong?

Comment: You can, of course, define $P_2$ as a path of two edges and three vertices (although this contradicts the common terminology, see e.g. [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_graph)), but it won't change anything.